# Has the ISS ever not had a lifeboat?

Tags: iss, crewed-spaceflight, soyuz-spacecraft

The International Space Station typically has one or more (manned) spacecraft docked. This is obviously to ferry crew to and from the station for each of the Expeditions. The Soyuz currently fulfils this role, but during its operation the Space Shuttle was also used.

In the event of an emergency the docked craft can be [used to evacuate](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5771/how-fast-can-the-crew-evacuate-the-iss-acrv) the ISS and return the crew safely to Earth.

At any point **has there ever *not* been the capacity for a *full* evacuation?**

Common sense says no - every crew member went up in a seat therefore there should always be one available for them to evacuate. Also crew safety is clearly  the primary concern.

However, [not all launches are full](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/20830/why-will-soyuz-ms-04-bring-only-two-crew-to-the-iss?rq=1), not all landings are full and [some astronauts](https://www.nasa.gov/astronauts/biographies/peggy-a-whitson) stay for multiple Expeditions, meaning the number of crew doesn't always match the number of available seats. This assumes that a full evacuation means every crew member has a seat.

NASA [had a plan](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19980007312.pdf) for a permanent escape vehicle, but this was cancelled.

**Edit:** I'd like to be certain that there were *no* situations (for example during relocation of a Soyuz craft - though this case [has been addressed](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/27793/has-the-iss-ever-not-had-a-lifeboat#comment83152_27794)). We can also ignore EVAs where technically [prompt evacuation would have been difficult](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3236/what-do-the-astronauts-do-whilst-the-air-lock-cycles). Granted, this may be difficult to prove definitively.

**Edit 2:** Although the conclusions seem pretty clear, I'm still not *entirely* convinced that there was never a short period without full evacuation capacity. There is some good discussion on [NASASpaceflight](https://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?topic=20543.msg557374#msg557374) on the rationale behind always ensuring evacuation. [This paper](https://web.archive.org/web/20061005052649/http://ston.jsc.nasa.gov/collections/TRS/_techrep/TM-2001-210198.pdf) also details the studies into a dedicated ACRV.

In the absence of an official word from one of the organisations involved, or unless someone can find a cross-referenced chronology of all astronaut activity, I'll accept the top answer as it's certain to be correct!

Comment: Unfortunately NASA has chosen to not make the ISS flight rules publicly available.  The definitive answer is in there.  There's a timeline of every docking and undocking here: https://www.nasa.gov/feature/visiting-vehicle-launches-arrivals-and-departures but it would be a lot of work to go through and check where each crewmember was at the time.  Most of the items on the web site link to a press release which give more details.  Here's the first Soyuz relocation, showing how the whole crew got in.https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/news/station/2001/iss01-06.html

Comment: @OrganicMarble Yeh it's a shame, I'd love to see one like the [Shuttle flight rules](https://www.jsc.nasa.gov/news/columbia/fr_generic.pdf). I guess it's withheld beacuse of the international aspect? Hopefully it'll be released after decommission (not that I'm looking forward to that day)! Wow, yeh it'd be a bit of an undertaking to go through all that!

Comment: I'd like that too! There was always so much more quality material released on Shuttle than ISS.  The Shuttle flight rules and a lot of the stuff on the JSC FDF page didn't get published until after Columbia though.  The shuttle flight rules before that had a big warning printed in them PUBLISHING ON ANY PUBLIC ELECTRONIC FORUM IS EXPRESSLY FORBIDDEN.  Why?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It never actually happened, but there was a case when this situation had the potential for happening.

That was the last shuttle flight, STS-135.

If a critical flaw in the thermal protection system of the Orbiter had been detected, the shuttle crew would have had to hang out in the ISS until they could be rotated home using spare Soyuz capability. They all got measured for the custom Soyuz seat liners to cover this case.

This was because there was no more available Orbiters for a rescue flight!

The stay could potentially have been quite long for the last crewmember, months, maybe a year if I remember correctly.

This was a major reason for having the final crew size be only four astronauts.

[Reference 1 - Houston Chronicle](https://blog.chron.com/finalmission/2011/04/soft-landings-in-moscow/) (may not be available in some regions)

[Reference 2 - spaceflightnow.com](https://spaceflightnow.com/shuttle/sts135/110706preview/index5.html)

Comment: To fly back with a Soyuz, they needed not only the custom seat liner, they needed also the space suit worn in the Soyuz. But they needed the suit for return in the Shuttle too. Suit and seat liner for the Soyuz may be broght to the ISS by the Soyuz itself.

Comment: Of course, if any Soyuz mission was stuck in a similar fashion, the same thing would have happened.

Comment: There was the potential of a Shuttle rescue mission though, before the last one.  Not quickly, of course.

Comment: There was also potential for two shuttle crews to get stranded on ISS that way...

Comment: How long would it take to prep, find a launch window for, and return in a rescue Orbiter?

Comment: BTW, what was the plan for the Shuttle in such case? Would they deorbit it, or would it remain as a permanent part of ISS?

Comment: @SF. After the Columbia failure a special wiring harness was fabricated and carried in the Orbiter. This harness allowed any of the operations that were previously only manual (like dropping the gear) to be controlled by the ground.  If the heat shield was critically damaged the plan was to install the harness and try and land the Orbiter at Edwards by remote control.

Comment: Though that would effectively have been the ISS acting as a lifeboat...

Comment: Funny, that reference link is not available in my region. I blame GDPR.

Comment: @OrganicMarble That's a really interesting set of circumstances! I'd quite like a reference or analysis to ensure there weren't even *short* periods.  I'm happy with this conclusions and I think it's definitive enough, but I'll wait a while to see if anything *more* definitive crops up.

Comment: @Jack: IIRC the only period after initial "unmanned" when ISS was without lifeboat, it was also unmanned - while moving Soyuz to a different port. The maneuver could have been performed by a single person or remote control easily, but the Soyuz was boarded by three crew members exactly for the reason so that they wouldn't be stranded in case the redocking maneuver fails.

Comment: @rene this article covers much of the same info: https://spaceflightnow.com/shuttle/sts135/110706preview/index5.html I hope you can access this one.

Comment: @OrganicMarble yes, that one works. I hope my comment wasn't seen as to blame you or push you to offer a different link. I appreciate the alternative link, thanks!

Comment: No problem at all, thanks for testing it. I'll add it to the answer.

Answer (score 10):

No. There has never been a point where a crew member had no way to 'leave'.

Even when the Shuttle did crew transfers, they took back 3 and left 3 behind or some combination of that approach.

The Soyuz capsule needs custom seat liners for each passenger, since landing is somewhat hard, and wrinkles and bumps will hurt a lot.

Part of finalizing the crew transfer is when they move their seat liners into their appropriate Soyuz capsule.

When the Russian segment crew is reduced to 2, from three that leaves a seat open for a possible tourist or other country to pay for a short visit.  In those cases, the new Soyuz typically arrives and later the old Soyuz leaves.  Thus the tourist hangs around for a week or so till the old Soyuz is set to land.

Comment: Thank you. Do you possibly have any sources for this? Is this true even for operations like Soyuz relocation? I appreciate that *dis*proof is much harder in this case!

Comment: @geoffc is right. There's a question on this site somewhere about crews landing on different vehicles than they launched on, I think there's an analysis there that might help you.

Comment: And yes, for the relocations, they all had to pile into the Soyuz in case there was a failure that forced them to deorbit.

Comment: @Jack I was thinking about how could prove this, and not sure you can.

Comment: This is what I was remembering but maybe not too useful after all. https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/18933/how-many-people-have-returned-to-earth-in-a-different-type-of-vehicle-than-the-o/21743

Answer (score 3):

For the entire time that the ISS has been occupied, there has been enough transportation to return to Earth. The only instance where anything different might have occurred was if there was a Soyuz mission when a Space Shuttle was docked. We can see the spacecraft that have visited at [this chart](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/visiting-vehicle-launches-arrivals-and-departures). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Space_Shuttle_missions) lists the number up/down from each Space Shuttle mission. STS-121 was the only mission that left more people at the ISS then it brought there. Prior to that mission, there were only 2 astronauts on the ISS. STS-121 left 3.

It seems to me that every [Soyuz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Soyuz_missions) capsule has brought the same number of people that it took with it. Thus, there has always been a lifeboat.

For bonus, here is the number of seats on Soyuz/ Space Shuttle docked to the ISS at any one time.
[image]

Comment: Where does this chart come from?  6 Soyuz seats + 8 shuttle seats does not add up to 20.

Comment: I made it. Technically there are 11 shuttle seats, and everything I can find says there were 3 soyuz on the ISS, but that does seem off... Will see if I can find a mistake in my source data.

Comment: There were not 11 shuttle seats, ever.  The largest crew was 8. https://www.nasa.gov/pdf/566250main_SHUTTLE%20ERA%20FACTS_040412.pdf  The largest number of people on the ISS ever was 13. https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/21759/how-many-times-were-there-thirteen-people-inside-the-iss-is-it-hard-on-the-stat

Comment: It seems like 7 might be a better choice. It seems that 11 was the max with a rescue configuration, and 7 would be a more realistic number. I must have the order wrong for one of the missions... Sigh.

Comment: Found the number, replaced STS seats with 7, and made it look a bit smoother. What do you think?

Comment: Those numbers "feel" a lot better!

Comment: INteresting that every Soyuz brought the same number up and down, even though they might not have been the same crew. I guess it makes sense though.

Comment: Very few Soyuz launch that are not full. It just doesn't make sense to do that. And actually, since the Space Shuttle stopped flying, most of the time in recent days one lands on the same Soyuz that one launched on.